# How to add header to downloadPage?

Tags: twisted

How to add custom header ( for example header 'accept-encoding: gzip' ) for downloadPage in Twisted ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at [the API documentation for `downloadPage`](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.web.client.downloadPage.html), you'll notice that it accepts `*args` and `**kwargs`.  It refers you to `HTTPDownloader` for documentation regarding those parameters.

If you look at [the API documentation for `HTTPDownloader`](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.web.client.HTTPDownloader.html), you'll see that it accepts a `headers` argument.  This argument isn't documented, but it's what you're looking for.  Its value should be a `dict` mapping header name to header value.  So,

```
downloadPage(..., headers={'accept-encoding': 'gzip'})
```

should do what you want.  Also, note the newer client API provided by Twisted, [twisted.web.client.Agent](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/web/howto/client.html).  Since Twisted 11.1, this [supports content encodings at a higher level](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/11.1.0/api/twisted.web.client.ContentDecoderAgent.html), and has [specific support for gzip](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/11.1.0/api/twisted.web.client.GzipDecoder.html).